# Communicate Wordpress passwords to external platform via API

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I would like to make sure to pass the general word in Wordpress to an external platform (connected via API).

I can pass all the parameters I need except the password, how can I proceed?

Please ask if you need more information, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more details about your problem, or ask another question. Passwords in WordPress databases are hashed, and have values like this: `$P$B2g7kq1z76SniZA6DznREDACTEDvYB0`.

Comment: More info please! What do you want to achieve?